# Im creating a basic area of circle calculator using a function. The program always returns a 1?

Tags: c++, function, return

As you can probably tell by my code, I'm a C++ beginner, practicing functions/return statements. I've attempted to create a basic program that calculates the area of a circle using the radius, which is given through user input. For some reason, the program always returns a 1? No doubt I've missed something simple, but for the life of me I can't see any problems?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

double areaofcircle(double Radius) {
    return M_PI * pow(Radius, 2);
}

int main () {
    double Radius;

    cout << "Enter the radius of your circle \n";
    cin >> Radius;
    cout << "The area of your circle equals  " << areaofcircle;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Listen to the compiler warnings; `areaofcircle` is treated as a function pointer: https://godbolt.org/z/rE55Kz8vr You need to call the function and I recommend printing a newline at the end of the output: `... << areaofcircle(Radius) << '\n';`

Comment: tip: `std::cout` can swallow almost anything and may trigger unexpected conversions. You get a nice compiler error if instead you write `double a = areaofcircle;  std::cout << a;`

Comment: For an even more bizarre-looking result, try `cout << "The area of your circle equals  " << std::boolalpha << areaofcircle;` (For something less bizarre, [enable warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
cout << "The area of your circle equals  " << areaofcircle(Radius);
```

In C++ when you call a function you must use parentheses `()` and any parameters to the function are placed between the parentheses separated by commas.

You actually know this because you did the right thing when you called `pow`, but not when you called your own function. The rules are the same, whether it's your function or one of the standard library functions.